# Cual es la forma correcta de acomodar mis rutas?

Tags: angular

estoy aprendiendo lazy routing en angular en un pequeño proyecto, pero me encontré una pequeña problemática al acomodar mis rutas, primero, te muestro mis rutas:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [ //main solo sirve como router principal
   {path: 'entrada', loadChildren: () => import('./entradas/entradas.module').then(res => res.EntradasModule)},
   {path: 'perfil', loadChildren: () => import('./perfil/perfil.module').then(res => res.PerfilModule)},
   {path: 'mensajes', loadChildren: () => import('./mensajes/mensajes.module').then(res => res.MensajesModule)},
   {path: 'configuracion', loadChildren: () => import('./configuracion/configuracion.module').then(res => res.ConfiguracionModule)},
   {path: 'users', loadChildren: () => import('./usuarios/usuarios.module').then(res => res.UsuariosModule)},
   {path: 'coordinador', loadChildren: () => import('./coordinador/coordinador.module').then(res => res.CoordinadorModule)}
 ]},
 {path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(res => res.AuthModule)},
 {path: 'logout', loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(res => res.AuthModule)}
 ];
```

Bien, estas rutas están cargadas en mi app.component así y según entiendo la ruta vacía, login y logout están en este router outlet y que dentro de la ruta vacía abra que poner otro para las hijas

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Por ende, ese router outlet abre este otro en MainComponent el cual carga una navbar y todas las rutas hijas

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Esta así para que la navbar este presente en cada de mis rutas hijas, el problema es que no se cómo hacer para que cuando entre a la ruta hija en el router outlen cargue mi ruta 'entrada', vi una forma que era ponerle `{path: '**', redirectTo: 'entrada'}`, así toda ruta que no sea las que declare irán a 'entradas' perooo si lo pongo 'login' y 'logout' no cargan, la aplicación actúa como si no existiera y solo refresca la página en entrada

Answer (score 0):

Este fragmento de codigo `{path: '**', redirectTo: 'entrada'}` prodrias colocarlo al final de todas tus rutas, ya que la lectura de rutas es secuencial en angular!

Comment: Lo modifique y no funciona , no me redirige sigue cargando localhost vacio y busco localhost/entrada :/, revise en internet y creo algo hice mal, la verdad no entiendo